# Piecewise functions in Julia when the domain of the sub-function is different

Tags: julia

Suppose I have a piecewise function foo(x) which is equal to x if x <= 0 and log(x) if x > 0. This function accepts a vector as an argument. So I tried the following:

```
function foo(x)
    (x .<= 0) .* x + (x .> 0) .* log(x)
end
```

Obviously this doesn't work when x < 0 as it tries to evaluate everything (even though it would be multiplied with 0. Any better way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you could try:

```
foo(x) = x > 0 ? log(x) : x
```

which assumes `x` is a scalar.

Then if `v` is a vector when you use it simply broadcast it like this `foo.(v)`.

Comment: Thanks! I read somewhere that Julia optimizes stuff so broadcasting doesn't take that much longer than vectorizing the function. Tried what you suggested with my function (different from this), and vectorizing is 5x faster. Ended up doing: `tmp[x <= 0] = x[x <= 0]; tmp[x > 0] = log(x[x > 0])`.

Comment: Which version of Julia are you on? On current release of Julia this code does not run. I guess you are missing some dots in your code (before comparison operator and after `log`). I have benchmarked it against `foo.(v)` I have suggested and it seems to be two times slower  on current release of Julia.

Comment: Sorry, yes, there should be dots there. Upon carefully inspecting it, broadcasting seems to give a consistent performance (0.06 sec) while my version could be anywhere from 0.05 sec to 0.2 sec. Thanks a lot!